# Is it possible to share an AWS resource to the entire organization via Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We have IaC for a replacement transit gateway, but I can't see a way to share it to the entire organization via Terraform, although I can do it through the console.
I've tried doing this both with the organisationID and the parent account number, but both result in errors:

```
resource "aws_ram_resource_share" "default" {
  count                     = var.ram_resource_share_enabled ? 1 : 0
  name                      = var.resource_share_name
  allow_external_principals = var.allow_external_principals
}
    
# Share the Transit Gateway with the Organization if RAM principal was not provided
data "aws_organizations_organization" "default" {
  count = var.ram_resource_share_enabled && !local.ram_principals_provided ? 1 : 0
}
    
resource "aws_ram_resource_association" "default" {
  count              = var.ram_resource_share_enabled ? 1 : 0
  resource_arn       = aws_ec2_transit_gateway.tgw.arn
  resource_share_arn = aws_ram_resource_share.default[0].id
}
    
resource "aws_ram_principal_association" "default" {
  for_each           = local.ram_principals
  principal          = each.value
  resource_share_arn = aws_ram_resource_share.default[0].id
}
```

There is obviously more code not included, but the `local.ram_principals` value is where I've tried to populate with either the organizationID (e.g. ["o-nb1000a1"]) or the parent account ID (e.g. 111122223333).

The organisationID returned error of `Error: "principal" doesn't look like AWS Account ID (exactly 12 digits)` and the parent accountID just created the share in that account, not the whole organization.

I'm just not convinced it can be done with Terraform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the docs, [resource sharing within AWS Organizations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ram/latest/userguide/getting-started-sharing.html#getting-started-sharing-orgs) has to be enabled first. After that, you will be able to share the resource within the organization:

```
resource "aws_ram_principal_association" "example" {
  principal          = data.aws_organizations_organization.default[0].arn
  resource_share_arn = aws_ram_resource_share.default[0].arn
}
```

Comment: Hi Marko, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately resource sharing was already enabled here so the errors are still happening

Comment: It was enabled as described in the documentation?

Comment: Ok, turned out it was a bug in my code, my apologies.  I set a variable value for ram_principals, but that wasn't relevant.  I needed to leave that value blank for the aws_organizations_organization data source to correctly populate.  As soon as I removed that value, the code built successfully.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. :)